# Excel - border around cells with same values (conditional foratting)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to create a border around cells that have the same value in column B like in the picture below (using conditional formatting)? Or would this have to be done using VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can using multiple conditional formatting rules.

In your example it's very easy to manually just add the outside borders (assuming this range won't change).

Then select the range `B2:D14` and add a conditional formatting rule through formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,$B2)=1
```

Make sure to apply the top border formatting and press OK.

That's it...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want your range to change you can use the following three conditions:

[image]

(note that for this to work, the first row needs to either be blank or be a header)